# How to insert a line between two lines which match a certain pattern in Notepad++

Tags: command-line, notepad++

This is my text file

```
echo Move date ahead 18 days to 30-09-2016
date 30-09-2016
echo Basic Rule Backups
echo Move date ahead 1 day to 1-10-2016
date 1-10-2016
echo date ahead 1 day to 2-10-2016
date 2-10-2016
```

Using Notepad++ or even Notepad, is there anyway to add an additional line "pause" only if the succeeding line is a "date" command.
Essentially this should be the output after replacement.

```
echo Move date ahead 18 days to 30-09-2016
pause
date 30-09-2016
echo Basic Rules 
echo Move date ahead 1 day to 1-10-2016
pause
date 1-10-2016
echo date ahead 1 day to 2-10-2016
pause
date 2-10-2016
```

If I can a general regular expression that can aid me in all such replacements, I'd really appreciate that

Comment: I have little knowledge about batch scripts or notepad++. Would it help you to see how the same could be accomplished in bash, maybe to base your own batch script on it? I ask first to not add useless answers to your question.

Comment: Sure that'll help

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments of the question, here's the bash script that would fulfil this purpose. Cheers

```
#!/bin/bash
### set input and output file names
input=test.txt
output=pause.txt

## run the script
while read foo; do echo $foo >> $output
   if [ "$(echo $foo | grep date)" != "" ]
      then echo "pause" >> $output
   fi
done < $input


### EXPLANATION
### The while loop runs until the input runs out of lines
### It takes one line and echo it out in a new file
### It makes an if check. It takes the line and checks if there is the 
### word 'date' in it. If yes, then the whole line will be the output,
### if no, it will be empty
### The if check checks if it is empty. If it is not empty
### (,hence date was present), it adds an additional line 
### saying 'pause' into the new file
### you will end up with two files. One with, one without pause.
```

EDIT 1:

As DavidPostill pointed out, I misunderstood the request. But echoing pause before writing the line and adding an additional reversed check for `echo` (stays blank when echo is found) should do the job. Thanks David!

```
 #!/bin/bash
### set input and output file names
input=test.txt
output=pause.txt

## run the script
while read foo; do
   if [ "$(echo $foo | grep date | grep -v echo)" != "" ]
      then echo "pause" >> $output
   fi
    echo $foo >> $output
done < $input
```

Comment: Did you test this? I don't think it will match the output required by the OP - it will also add `pause` after lines containing `echo date ...` which is not what was asked for.

Comment: you're right, I missunderstood the OP in two points. I thought pause should be added after any date and also after the actual date line. Well, it's kind of an easy fix. Give me a moment

Comment: It's still not correct :/ the last line `date 2-10-2016` is not processed and is missing from `pause.txt`. The last line should also have pause before it ...

Comment: Hmm.. I just checked at my end and it prints it correctly. This is what it outputs `echo Move date ahead 18 days to 30-09-2016
pause
date 30-09-2016
echo Basic Rule Backups
echo Move date ahead 1 day to 1-10-2016
pause
date 1-10-2016
echo date ahead 1 day to 2-10-2016
pause
date 2-10-2016` Bad to read in the comments, but as you see, it has added a `pause` in the second to last line

Comment: Here is my output http://imgur.com/4XX70gM

Comment: Ah. I know what is happening (I think). I copied the test data from the question **and the last line did not have a cr/lf**.

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I insert a line before another line which matches a pattern?

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `^(date.*)$`
- Set "Replace with" to `pause\r\n\1`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

[image]

Notes:

- The above assumes you are editing a text file with Windows EOLs, `\r\n`.
- If you are using files with different EOLs you can convert them to Windows EOLs using Menu "Edit" > "EOL Conversion".
- If you aren't working with Windows EOL, and you don't wish to convert them, use the following instead:

  - Use `\n` instead of `\r\n` for Unix/OS X EOLs
  - Use `\r` instead of `\r\n` for Mac OS (up to version 9) EOLs

---

#### Further reading

- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)